# instead of trigger result output

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have created my first trigger. Please see the code section for the trigger below.

The triggers and the results are as expected, except for one thing.

So when I run the code below it will not insert the values into my table so the number of records remains unchanged.

```
insert into MatlabSearchPath(directory, userName)
values('madeup', 'default')
```

In the messages window though I get two lines. I don't understand why I see two lines and in particular 1 row affected - the number of records in my table hasn't changed?

```
(0 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
```

**Trigger**

```
create trigger trDefaultPathInsert on DVLP_QES.dbo.MatlabSearchPath
instead of insert
as
begin
declare @defCount int
declare @retVal int
select @defCount = count(userName) from inserted where userName = 'Default'

if (@defCount > 0)
begin
    select @retVal = count(HostName) from DVLP_QES.dbo.UserHostName where HostName = HOST_NAME()
    if (@retVal > 0)
    begin           
        insert into MatlabSearchPath select * from inserted
    end
    else
    begin
        insert into MatlabSearchPath select * from inserted where inserted.userName <> 'Default'
    end 
end
```

end

**Update**

I should mention that there a 3 triggers on this table, one is the trigger above the other one is a delete & the last one is an update

Comment: Are you sure both messages are from the same insert?  If you clear the messages window and run the insert do you always get two messages?

Comment: @MarkLeiber yes I've cleared the messages window and always get two messages back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger does the following:

1. Counts records you are trying to insert, where userName equals 'Default'
   In your case, count is 1.
   Pay attention to your collation - if it's case sensitive, you are going to skip that whole branch of code.
2. If you enter the if branch, next thing trigger checks is if there are rows in UserHostName table where HostName equals host name of your client; pay attention that you don't think it should be host name of your server or something like that
3. If you enter the TRUE-branch, it should insert everything to the table; however, if not, it shouldn't insert anything. Of course, except if the collation is case sensitive, then revert the logic.

I I were you, I would add PRINT statements into trigger, just to make sure how does it execute.

```
create trigger trDefaultPathInsert on DVLP_QES.dbo.MatlabSearchPath
instead of insert
as
begin
declare @defCount int
declare @retVal int
select @defCount = count(userName) from inserted where userName = 'Default'

PRINT '@defCount'
PRINT @defCount

if (@defCount > 0)
begin
    select @retVal = count(HostName) from DVLP_QES.dbo.UserHostName where HostName = HOST_NAME()

    PRINT '@retVal'
    PRINT @retVal 

    if (@retVal > 0)
    begin           
        PRINT 'TRUE-BRANCH'
        insert into MatlabSearchPath select * from inserted
    end
    else
    begin
        PRINT 'FALSE-BRANCH'
        insert into MatlabSearchPath select * from inserted where inserted.userName <> 'Default'
    end 
end
```

*EDIT*

It seems that the message about rows affected can't be controlled inside the trigger. Even the standard `SET NOCOUNT ON` on the trigger beginning won't stop it from showing. This gave me notion that the message is a result of the trigger being successfully finished by calling it with X rows, where X will eventually be in the `X row(s) affected` message.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677922/triggers-and-disabling-rows-affected-message) furtherly confirms the problem.

Comment: I get defcount =1, retval = 0, it then prints 'FALSE-BRANCH' then the usual 0 row(s) affected followed by 1 row(s) affected

Comment: Well, that's an easy one then, isn't it? Your select from `UserHostName` returns nothing. That's why no rows get inserted.

Comment: Yes the 0 row(s) affected is correct and what I'm expecting however its the 1 row(s) affected that comes after it that I don't understand

Comment: Actually it seems that SQL Server always appends this kind of message as last for the INSTEAD OF trigger. So, if you have 10 rows for insertion, it will print out '10 row(s) affected'. Weird.

Comment: Yeh that is weird wouldn't have found that out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The situation here if the first message indicating  cero is because the instead of trigger is uses to ignore the insert you sent and do instead whats in the trigger

You can debug your code with management studio